# Using Jquery 1.8.0 return false is not breaking an each() loop

Tags: jquery, loops, break, each

Here is the script I am using.

```
    $('.row').each(function(){
        $(this).each(function(){
            if($(this).find('.name').val()==""){

                $(this).find('.name').val(data.name);
                $(this).find('.autonomy').val(data.autonomy);
                $(this).find('.purpose').val(data.purpose);
                $(this).find('.flow').val(data.flow);
                $(this).find('.relatedness').val(data.relatedness);
                $(this).find('.challenge').val(data.challenge);
                $(this).find('.mastery').val(data.mastery);
                $(this).find('.colour').val(data.colour);
                done=true;
            }
            if(done==true){
                alert("here");
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
```

It just seems to totally ignore the return false and I can't seem to work out why!

Comment: Why are there two `.each()`?

Comment: That was indeed the issue! Worked it out later in the day :)

Answer (score 2):

No need in nested `each`. Remove the inner one, and `return false` will work:

```
$(".row").each(function() {
    // ...
    if (done === true) {
        alert("here");
        return false;
    }
});​
```

Comment: You don't know his HTML do be sure that he doesn't need the nested each.

Comment: @FábioSilva Believe me, it doesn't matter.

Comment: But maybe he wants to make a nested loop (for every element inside every row). Your solution just runs every row. But I see your point in this case: the second **this** is == to the first **this**, so he is always accessing the *row* elements

Answer (score 2):

Show us your DOM first.

The return that you have only stops the second each(). If you want to stop the first one you need to do it in other way.

Sorry I can't comment, but my reputation does not allow it.